# Supplying data to an immutable texture storage

Tags: c++, opengl

Is there a way to directly (i.e., not a copy or a fill) supply data to a texture with immutable storage that isn't `glTexSubImage*`? I know there might not be an actual need for a separate function to fulfill this role, but I do wonder why you can't specify the data in the same line you allocate your memory (in the same manner as immutable buffer objects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do wonder why you can't specify the data in the same line you allocate your memory (in the same manner as immutable buffer objects).

Textures are far more complex than buffer objects.

The immutable storage APIs for textures allocate all of the specified mipmap levels for that texture. However, the [various pixel transfer functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Storage_contents) only ever upload, *at most*, a single mipmap level's worth of pixel data in a single operation. There is no provision in any pixel transfer operation to transfer more than a single mipmap level of data. Indeed, the [process of pixel transferring](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) only makes sense with a single image of a given dimensionality (array textures are considered treated as a higher-dimensional image). Mipmap levels change their size from layer to layer, which makes the pixel transfer operation change its meaning. Particularly with regard to some of the [pixel transfer parameters](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_parameters) like sub-image selectors.

So if you're uploading to a texture with multiple mipmaps, you're going to need to make multiple calls anyway. So what's one more?

Furthermore, note that `glTexImage*` and `glCompressedTexImage*` take different parameters. The former takes pixel data via [pixel transfer functionality](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer), and the latter takes pre-compressed data. But they both allocate storage. If you're going to make `glTexStorage*` more analogous to `glTexImage*`, then you have to also add `glCompressedTexStorage*`. So now you have another series of functions, and the only difference is what kind of upload they do.

By contrast, buffers only contain a single array of bytes, and there's only one way to upload to them.

Overall, it's better to just use the existing SubImage infrastructure for uploading, and have allocation be entirely separate from that.